# Save a generated QR code image on .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui, qrcoder

I used QRCoder in order to generate a random QR code when clicking a button like so:

```
private void OnRNGClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Generates a "random" number to be used when making the QR Code
     Random rng = new Random();
     int sixDigRNG = rng.Next(1, 11);
     string rngString = sixDigRNG.ToString();

     //Creates the QR Code
     QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
     QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(rngString, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.L);
     PngByteQRCode qRCode = new PngByteQRCode(qrCodeData);

     //Displays the QR Code
     byte[] qrCodeBytes = qRCode.GetGraphic(20);
     QrCodeImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(qrCodeBytes));
 }
```

I want to have another button that when clicked will use the Save method to save this png QR Code to whichever type of platform the user is using (Android, IOS, Windows ect...). My issue is that whenever I try to use the Save method (Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) it says that there is no definition for this method. I think it might be because I am generating a QR instead of editing an image. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

I have also tried using System.Windows.Forms to make a form for the user to save the image with, but my .NET MAUI application did not recognize this namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, qrCodeBytes);
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Since qrCodeBytes is a local variable of my OnRNGClicked event handler, how do you access it in a separate buttons event handler in .NET MAUI? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make it a class level variable or property

Comment: By making my event handler a class with qrCodeBytes as a public variable?

Comment: make `qrCodeBytes` a class level variable